# Manufacturer of a product Magento

Tags: php, magento

I started off with magento, and got stuck at a very odd problem,
I have one root category, two child catgories, each having subcategories and products, i want manufacturer list from each of the two child categories which are under the root category.

i started of with giving root category id as 3.
please look at the code below..

```
$root=3;
    $rootcategories=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($root,1,false,true,false);    
foreach($rootcategories as $c=>$Cat){
    $product = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                           ->addCategoryFilter($Cat);
foreach($product as $pro){
    $pId=$pr['entity_id'];
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId);
    $manufacturers[$c][]=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
}
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($manufacturers);
die;
```

i'm supposed to get list of manufacturers from this code, but i get a 'NO' for each product in each of the category.

Comment: Do you have the attribute to have "Used in Product Listing"?

Answer (score 1):

you don't make use of your `$pro` variable in your `foreach` loop :)

```
foreach($product as $pro) {
   echo $pro->getManufacturers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Work everywhere.

```
$manufacturer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do

```
$_product->getData('manufacturer');
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$root=3;
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root)->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($categories AS $cat)
{
$productCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($cat);
foreach($productCollection AS $product)
{
echo $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer').'<br/>';
}
}
```

Something like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Returns NULL.. :( tried this earlier.. also tried getatributetext, getattribute n others help please..

Comment: getAttributeText('manufacturer') returns bool(false). i know that manufacturer is specified and not missing, also note that i'm able to get attribute text for sku, weight, name etc.. other values of attribute but not the "Manufacturer" .. :( please help

Comment: Have you tried getting the manufacturer of a product? Not by getting the category first I mean.

Comment: yup.. and i was pretty much successful at that.. only that i got all the manufacturers, i wanted it specific for each of the parent category, for example, if one category is apparel i want nike addidas to list, n other is mobile phone i want htc nokia to be listed..

Comment: <?php $_product = $this->getProduct();
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>

Comment: Why don't you used mfg in Layered Navigation with results, and the categories be anchored.

Comment: used layered navigation.. couldn't find a better way out of this.. thanks. :)